# html2canvas not showing form elements properly

Tags: reactjs, html2canvas

I'm using React and Html2Canvas to capture a form on a button click. The form has four `select` nodes. Html2Canvas is saving the form as an image, but the selects inside are showing the first option in the rendered image. I'm wondering if I've configured this incorrectly either in html2canvas config or in react.

```
let options = {
  async: true,
  foreignObjectRendering: true,
  logging: false
};
let input = this.iceBreaker.current;
html2canvas(input, options).then(canvas => {
  if (canvas) {
    this.setState({
      imageRef: canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    });
  }
});
```

When the button is clicked, `imageRef` is downloaded as a PNG. Note that even appending the div to the body shows the same issue (it's for this reason that I didn't attach any other code). Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Elements with the absolute position are not rendering by default. Make sure all your elements are not absolute in position.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go: should be fairly clear...

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { canvasArray: [] };
    this.captureRef = React.createRef();
  }

  getScreenshotHandler = () => {
    html2canvas(this.captureRef.current).then(canvas =>
      this.setState({
        canvasArray: [canvas.toDataURL(), ...this.state.canvasArray],
      }),
    );
  };

  renderCanvas = () => {
    return this.state.canvasArray.map((canvas, i) => {
      return <img key={i} src={canvas} alt="screenshot" />;
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <div ref={this.captureRef} className="to-capture">
          <p>
            This enitre <code>div</code> will be captured
          </p>
        </div>
        <button onClick={this.getScreenshotHandler}>Get Screenshot!</button>
        <section>
          <h5>Your screenshots will be availbale below:</h5>
          {this.renderCanvas()}
        </section>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Live demo here: https://codesandbox.io/s/1r213057vq

Comment: This comment led me to the correct answer. `foreignObjectRendering: true` was allowing the SVG dropdown icons to look good when rendered in canvas, but was causing only the first select option to show in the form that we were capturing regardless of what was chosen. We had to use a different treatment for the icons and everything worked.